# Inputs which make two function have the same value

Tags: equation-solving, functions

Suppose I have two function `f(x1,...,xN)` and `g(x1,...,xN)`. How can I find the values `{x1,...,xN}` which makes the two function equal?

Is there some built-in function?
I think make two tables and comparing them will be time consuming.
One other solution might be minimizing `f-g`.
Is there any other way to get this done?

For my specific case f and g are polynomials with non-linear terms like x1*x5, x2*x6*...*x30.
each function has at least 7 variables.

Comment: I think that strongly depends on the nature of your "functions". Are we talking _functions_ in the mathematical sense?

Comment: What function to use depends on the character of `f` and `g` and the number of independent variables.  If one variable, use `FindRoot`.  In general, defining the two surfaces as regions and finding the minimum distance between them seems reasonable.

Comment: Look at FindInstance command (try to apply to f-g==0)

Comment: Also, consider `Reduce` applied to regions.

Comment: @Sascha Yes, these are mathematical function. Specifically, they are like polynomials with non linear terms like x1*x5.

Comment: Please edit your question to include two sample functions.

Comment: Do you need one solution or a representation of all of them?  I think it would be better to phrase this as "find $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $h(\mathbf{x}) = 0$".  It seems irrelevant that you have *two* functions.

Comment: Have a look at `SolveAlways` documentation.

Answer (score 4):

As a simple example, consider

```
f[x, y] := x^2 + 3 y
g[x, y] := x y
Reduce[f[x, y] == g[x, y], {x, y}]
(* -3 + x != 0 && y == x^2/(-3 + x) *)
```

To visualize the answer,

```
Show[Plot3D[{x^2 + 3 y, x y}, {x, -25, 25}, {y, -25, 25}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, "f, g"}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{x, x^2/(x - 3), x^3/(x - 3)}, {x, -25, 25}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u}, -25 < y < 25]]]
```

which shows the intersection of the two curves.

[image]

This approach (although not the plot) should generalize to higher dimensions.  Typically, the intersection of two seven-dimensional functions is either a six-dimensional surface, or null.